# what jquery code to find and place text when website is running?

Tags: jquery, text, replace

I have the following code on my html :

```
<div class="fleft"> 
    Design by: 
    <a href="http://text.com/ ">text.com</a>
    <br> 
    Copyright &copy; 2012 Lego Guru &ndash; Lego Creations Outside the Box 
    <br>
</div>
```

I like to run jquery so that when the website is online it will replace **text.com** with **axle.com**

Currently my Jquery code is the following but doesn't work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('text.com','axle.com'));
    });
});
```

pls note further that this is a wordpress site.. the problem is if you view the file which is footer.php you dont find any of the texts - appears they encrypted the code. It only generates the texts when the site is viewed on the browser.

Comment: While this is possible, you should really consider wrapping those blocks of code in something like `<span class="editme">text.com</span>`, which can be found and replaced far more efficiently.

Comment: What exactly "does not work"? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Unbalanced brackets. Use a JS debugger and you'd see the error yourself.

Comment: ok my site generates a footer text that are protected.. So I'd like to replace those text with my own.. but the only way to replace them is when the site is running since I cannot do that on the html itself.

Comment: Can you give us a link so we'd be able to see for ourselves?

Comment: @Moses ok this is the site.. http://legoguru.com/ as you can see the footer is generated by footer.php but the texts there are encrypted. so Im trying to use Jquery to replace them on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is replace all `a` elements which is not correct.

Try this.

```
var replace = 'axle.com';
$('a[href^=http://text.com]').attr('href', 'http://' + replace).text(replace);
```

Tested on your site.

```
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('a[href*="axillon.com"]').attr('href', 'http://yoursite.com')
                                   .text('your text');
});
```

Comment: the problem is if you view the file which is footer.php  you dont find any of the texts - appears they encrypted the code. It only generates the texts when the site is viewed on the browser.

Comment: Can you give me your site's url?

Comment: ok its http://legoguru.com/ as you can see the footer is generated by footer.php but the texts there are encrypted. so Im trying to use Jquery to replace them on runtime.

Comment: I just updated the answer. I doesn't matter if it encrypted in php. the final result still html (that's why it call client-side)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.location.hostname` :

```
$('a').each(function(){   
    $(this).html(window.location.hostname); 
});
```

**EDIT :**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
     var link = jQuery('#footer a').get(0);
     link.innerHTML = 'axle.com';
     link.href = 'http://www.axle.com';
});
```

Comment: ok my site generates a footer text that are protected.. So I'd like to replace those text with my own.. but the only way to replace them is when the site is running since I cannot do that on the html itself.

Comment: I don't get your point.
You are using a CMS like Wordpress or something ?

Could you precise ?

Comment: the problem is if you view the file which is footer.php  you dont find any of the texts - appears they encrypted the code. It only generates the texts when the site is viewed on the browser.

Comment: Ok, so the code is obfuscated. Are you able to modify the code by yourself ? If not, why ? Ask them (your client?) an unobfuscated version. 
If your are trying to modify an obfuscated website, it looks like this website don't belongs to you..

Comment: the site is mine.. its just its free template that I totally modified except for the footer text which is encrypted

Comment: So you should be able to access and use the admin pannel to edit the code directly online. Did you tried to put this code snippet at the bottom of your footer page ?

Comment: Ok I should give you the link to the site ... http://legoguru.com/ as you can see the footer is generated by footer.php but the texts there are encrypted. so Im trying to use Jquery to replace them on runtime.

Comment: I tried your code in a js file and called that file in the header.. is that the right way to do it?

Comment: I've edited my post. This last snippet should work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are just replacing it inside the content of anchor and not replacing it in the href. Try this.

```
$('a').each(function(){   
    this.href = this.href.replace('text.com','axle.com');
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace('text.com','axle.com');
});
```

Comment: Better use `outerHTML` for killing two birds with one stone (metaphorical birds, of-course).

Comment: `outerHTML` is not the right choice here and moreoever it isn't supported in all the browser.

Comment: the problem is if you view the file which is footer.php  you dont find any of the texts - appears they encrypted the code. It only generates the texts when the site is viewed on the browser.

Comment: The only browser which doesn't support `outerHTML` is FF versions 3-4, which in my opinion is SO not relevant nowadays. Other then that, why is it not the right choice here? Do you have an explanation?

Comment: One of the reason is cross browser support and other is outer html can contain many other things like class attribute with classes, inline styling, data attributes etc which we don't have to look for while replacing the text.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Ok I should give you the link to the site ... http://legoguru.com/ as you can see the footer is generated by footer.php but the texts there are encrypted. so Im trying to use Jquery to replace them on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('a').each(function ()
    {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('text.com', 'axle.com'));
    });
});
```

Comment: the problem is if you view the file which is footer.php  you dont find any of the texts - appears they encrypted the code. It only generates the texts when the site is viewed on the browser.

Comment: Ok I should give you the link to the site ... http://legoguru.com/ as you can see the footer is generated by footer.php but the texts there are encrypted. so Im trying to use Jquery to replace them on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good practice, but anyway, in the loop you need to check somehow that the website is online, maybe you can make an ajax call and on the success function replace the text

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for an `.each()` loop here. Use jQuery to select only the anchors with the desired `href` and modify them all at once.

I would try something like this:

```
$('a[href*="text.com"]').attr('href','http://axle.com').text('axle.com');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bUXDv/

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Caveat: this will replace links with "text.com" ANYWHERE in the `href`. If there's a possibility of it making undesirable matches like "text.com/contact/" or "hypertext.com", you need to be more specific with your selector.

Comment: the problem is if you view the file which is footer.php  you dont find any of the texts - appears they encrypted the code. It only generates the texts when the site is viewed on the browser.

Comment: I'm not at all clear what you mean. How is the footer "protected" or "encrypted"? Please try the above, and then explain EXACTLY why this solution doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Ok I should give you the link to the site ... http://legoguru.com/ as you can see the footer is generated by footer.php but the texts there are encrypted. so Im trying to use Jquery to replace them on runtime.

Comment: There's nothing encrypted in that footer. My browser's DOM debugger can read it just fine.

Comment: yes it doesnt show encrypted but if you check the file footer.php in the server it contains random texts like its encrypted.

Comment: Please tell us if you've TRIED the answers given to you so far.